# Waiting for Navigation Complete to continue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await

My team has been struggling for the Best Practices approach for handling the response from a Navigation for about 3 weeks now without a definitive answer.  We have both a WPF and a Windows Phone 8 solution where we share a common code base.

For Phone 8, we display our company's splash screen and start initializing our data.  Due to our complex nature, we have a very long list of steps to initialize before the application is fully operational.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) 
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New) 
    {
        BeginAppStartup();
        return;
    }

        ....

void BeginAppStartup() 
{
    // Initialization of settings and environment
```

At this point, we need to optionally display up to 5 different pages requesting additional data.  So we check our commands, and if executable, then we navigate and optionally display a Communication Page, a Login Page, or several other possible pages.

```
    if( condition )
        DisplayLoginPage();
```

In WPF, this would be easy since we have modal dialogs and can wait for the user's input before continuing.  But in the asynchronous world of WP8, we no longer have this.

To accommodate this platform, we have implemented a wide array of attempts, including saving the next command to execute.  The only place that I believe that we are assured that the page is closed is in the OnNavigatedTo of the splash page.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) 
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back) 
    {
        // If we are returning to the splash from another set up page, check if there are new actions to perform

        if (_startupAction != null) 
        {
            _startupAction();
            return;
        }
```

Unfortunately, this is only marginally acceptable since the Login page doesn't close properly since all of our action is in the UI thread.  The code continues, but the splash page is hidden behind the still visible Login page.

We have also tried out AutoResetEvents, but since we must Navigate out of the UI thread, we can't block the UI thread.  We've also tried Task.Run with similar issues.

```
    // Doesn't work.

void ShowLoginPage() 
{
    if (condition) 
    {
        _manualResetEvent.Reset();
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Login.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
        _manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

We've also tried the async/await tasks, but we encounter similar problems.  I believe that this is the best solution, but we're not having any better luck than previously.

**So back to the question:  What is the Best Practice for Navigating from a splash page, optionally to a login page, and then to await for the login page to close completely before continuing?**

This sounds like a very common scenario, yet I'm baffled!  Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Id probably just create a simple state machine holding the state of login.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's not an issue of state.  It's 'when are you guaranteed that the navigated window is closed'.  I was hoping that it was during 'OnNavigatedTo' on the Splash page, but it's not.  The login page is still visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not difficult to provide a functionality similar to a modal dialog. I'm not sure if it is a great UI design decision, but it certainly can be done. [This MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mitsu/archive/2007/05/07/how-to-simulate-modal-windows-inside-a-single-wpf-window-using-anonymous-methods.aspx) describes how to do it with `UserControl` as a custom adorner. It was written in 2007, by that time there was no `async/await` nor WP8.

I'm going to show how to do a similar thing using [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) control (which is present in both WPF and WP8) and `async/await`. Here's the functional part:

```
private async void OpenExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await ShowPopup(this.firstPopup);
    await ShowPopup(this.secondPopup);
}
```

Each popup can and should be data-bound to the `ViewModel`.

**C#** (a WPF app):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Wpf_22297935
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/q/22297935/1768303

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        EventHandler ProcessClosePopup = delegate { };

        private void CloseExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ProcessClosePopup(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        // show two popups with modal-like UI flow
        private async void OpenExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await ShowPopup(this.firstPopup);
            await ShowPopup(this.secondPopup);
        }

        private void CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        // helpers

        async Task ShowPopup(Popup popup)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            EventHandler handler = (s, e) => tcs.TrySetResult(true);
            this.ProcessClosePopup += handler;

            try
            {
                EnableControls(false);

                popup.IsEnabled = true;
                popup.IsOpen = true;

                await tcs.Task;
            }
            finally
            {
                EnableControls(true);

                popup.IsOpen = false;
                popup.IsEnabled = false;

                this.ProcessClosePopup -= handler;
            }
        }

        void EnableControls(bool enable)
        {
            // assume the root is a Panel control
            var rootPanel = (Panel)this.Content;

            foreach (var item in rootPanel.Children.Cast<UIElement>())
                item.IsEnabled = enable;
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_22297935.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" CanExecute="CanExecute" Executed="OpenExecuted" />
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" CanExecute="CanExecute" Executed="CloseExecuted"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>

    <DockPanel>
        <Border Padding="5">
            <StackPanel>

                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>Main:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Height="20"></TextBox>
                    <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50">Open</Button>
                </StackPanel>

                <Popup Name="firstPopup" AllowsTransparency="true" Placement="Center">
                    <Border Background="DarkCyan" Padding="5">
                        <StackPanel Background="DarkCyan" Width="200" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <TextBlock>First:</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox Height="20"></TextBox>
                            <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50">Close</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>

                <Popup Name="secondPopup" AllowsTransparency="true" Placement="Center">
                    <Border Background="DarkGray" Padding="5">
                        <StackPanel Background="DarkGray" Width="200" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <TextBlock>Second:</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox Height="20"></TextBox>
                            <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50">Close</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>

            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks Noseratio!  I really appreciate this.  It will definitely give me some good ideas on how to tackle the problem.  I am definitely looking at how to do it 'right' and don't mind changing over everything to do it how it 'should' be done.  This is such a common scenario (show a page, get info, exit page, respond to data) that I'm baffled by the complexity of it

Comment: @PhillipDavis, the popup is a legit piece of WP UI, check [this](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_Pop-Ups_in_Windows_Phone). I'm a bit confused though, is your goal to have a popup with a [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.page(v=vs.105).aspx) inside it? I.e. a popup with navigation?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with such complex navigation, you should resort to creating your own navigation service. Instead of using NavigationService.Navigate, use your own wrapper over it.

In case of login page being after splash screen (and optionally), but before some other, you can always remove the page from backstack after navigation. So in this case you *always* navigate forward to another page and your custom service should remove last page if it is, say, a login page.